# Difference between 交替 and 交代

Tags: words, nuances, orthography, homophonic-kanji

Is there any difference between 交替 and 交代 or are they completely interchangeable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're mostly interchangeable.

If you want to be nit-picky, 交替 is for regularly occurring changes, and 交代 is for one-time changes, but this is not a hard-set rule.

Comment: +1 but I missed your line, **but this is not a hard-set rule.**. It looks like they are more kind of the "hard-set rule" though..　http://知っ得袋.biz/443.html ( I am afraid I can not provide the link well. )

Comment: I still feel, though, that what the link and I have said is still more of a tendency than a rule.

Comment: Even the site says **つまり、スポーツの選手交代など、一度変わった後は、もう元に戻ることができない状況の事を「交代」と呼ぶのです。** Translated : **交代 is used to express irreversible situations such like when a sports player is changed and the previous player will not return**??

Comment: Yes, that would be the *technically correct* way of selecting which to use, but in practice that rule is often ignored. In particular, I think 交代 is used more often than 交替 (even in circumstances where 交替 would be proper assuming this rule).

Comment: In practice! Do you use the word 交代 for 交替, for instance, in business letters? And what do you intend to mean by "technically correct"? I think 6th grades will fail the entrance examination if they take your "advice".

Comment: So, you are suggesting, since 交代 and 交替 are Kanji compounds respectively, would you suggest to use 交代制度 for 交替制度? for example, to denote the office regulations of guard men. In that case the former doesn't make sense at all to me. The former then would denote a guard man will never come back to his original position again.

Comment: In my answer I said they were *mostly* interchangeable. Sure there are some compounds with other words where changing it wouldn't make sense. What I am saying is that sometimes you *will* find that 交代 is used in place of 交替. In fact, newspapers use 交代 *much* more often than 交替. As I said before, it is a tendency, not a hard-set rule.

Comment: Mr. Blavius, if you insist so much, please give me your counter answer to my post. ( at the comment line, welcomed. )

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give further information since Mr. Blavius asserts **交代 is for one-time changes, but this is not a hard-set rule.** and per choco san's advice.

From this site [http://知っ得袋.biz/443.html](http://%E7%9F%A5%E3%81%A3%E5%BE%97%E8%A2%8B.biz/443.html)

From the site,

> 交代・・・役目などが一回限りでかわる時
>
> 交替・・・かわって行うことが繰り返されるとき

Translated

> 交代　--- one time change of roles or jobs or plays etc etc,
>
> 交替　--- repetitive change of roles or jobs or plays etc, etc.

And from the above

> つまり、スポーツの選手交代など、一度変わった後は、もう元に戻ることができない状況の事を「交代」と呼ぶのです。これに対し「交替」の「かわって行うことが繰り返されるとき」というのは、AからBに変わって、またAに戻ったり、またBに戻ったりする時を指します。例えば、警備の担当や仕事の当番など、何回も変わったりする時には「交替」を使うということですね！

Translated

> So, 交代 is used to express irreversible situations such like when a sports player is changed and the previous player will not return. On the other hand, 交替, is used to express the repetitive motions, such as a person A does a job then afterward another B take over the job. The example is guard men or day and night duties. One person can not do the job 24 hours and 5 days in succession, so that in such a case 交替 is used.

Examples respectively from the source.

交代

> 会社が世代交代していく。

Translated

> Generational changes of company's important members ( such as bosses ).

**Would the previous bosses come back 50 years later? Quite unlikely**

交替

> 昼夜交替

Translated

> Day and night shift ( works ).

**A person A can not work day and night 5 days a week ( for example ). Please think about the above mentioned guard men's case kindly**

Have a nice day.

Comment: 明鏡国語辞典によると、次のとおりです。『「交代」は、「世代交代」のように、その役目などが一回限りの場合に、「交替」は、「昼夜交替」「交替での勤務」のように、繰り返される場合に使われることが多い。**ただし絶対的なものではなく**、「参勤交代」などは伝統的に「交代」を使う。』

Comment: You aren't understanding what I am trying to say at all. I am not saying that any of these points are invalid. The article and I came to the same conclusion- that 交替 is for regularly occurring changes, and 交代 is for one-time changes. I added, though, that often this rule is broken (but not necessarily in the examples you gave). In particular, 交代 is more often used (even when 交替 would make sense), especially in newspapers.

Comment: 参勤交代 [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankin-k%C5%8Dtai) is a **one-year change**. And it is not assumed Subordinate A should return to Edo again ( May be he might remain at his country next time. ). So do you suggest you can use 参勤交替 for 参勤交代? As the dictionary says, for some **traditional** cases, they can be swappable...

Comment: So **what kind of cases** the rule is broken?? Only some traditional cases. And furthermore, as you know, regarding 参勤交代, the subordinates of lords in Edo era went and came back from Edo to his lord's fief **a year by  year**. Would you use 昼夜交代 for 昼夜交替？ It won't make sense at all. Would you choose the former word then if you were an owner of a business on  contract papers???????

Comment: Let's then change the Kanji then as an example, since they are Kanji compounds. 世代( Sedai ) meaning, generations, suggesting **different layers of ages** ( which is, **unswappable** ), whereas, there is no word such like 世替 ( Setai?? ), since, the generation can not be changed **repetitively**.

Comment: I said before, I don't disagree that they have subtle differences- but people tend to use one for the other (particularly 交代 for 交替) anyway. Also, look at the accepted answer on [this question on chiebukuro.](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1111995276)

Comment: Okay, then I would like to say, **I learned a lot thanks to the questioner**.

Comment: 個人的には殆ど区別しませんし、「交代勤務」も「交替勤務」もごく普通に見ます（ちなみにWikipediaだと[この記事](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%A4%E4%BB%A3%E5%8B%A4%E5%8B%99)は交代が優勢で[この記事](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E5%8B%A4%E5%8B%99)は交替が優勢ですが、誰も議論すらしてません）。事実上厳格な使い分けはされていないということで構わないと思いますし、「交代制度だと全く意味が通らない」と言い張る人は初めて見ました。

Comment: では参勤交替と言い換える事が出来る訳でしょうか？塾関係の会社経営に携わる者としてそのレベルだと中学校の試験で落ちますよ（笑）。

Comment: 正直申し上げてBlaviusさんの知恵袋の件もベストアンサーの人の　**「交替式」；新旧官人の交代の時の事務引継ぎに関する法令またはその集大成**　の前者の「交替」は入れ替わりの可能性を意味し,後者の交代は暫くその官吏が変わらないという意味での時間的スパンの長さだと思います。その下のベストアンサー以外の人は区別しています。

Comment: "では参勤交替と言い換える事が出来る訳でしょうか" >> いいえ。なぜなら明鏡に『「参勤交代」などは伝統的に「交代」を使う。』とありますので。伝統的にそうなっている物は含まないでしょう。

Comment: ではどういう「基準」なのでしょうか？snaiboatさんは参勤交代の例を挙げていますが…。すみません仕事ですので失礼します。

Comment: "snaiboatさんは参勤交代の例を挙げていますが">> えっ、どこでですか？上のコメントでは彼女は辞書を引用しているだけで、彼女が「参勤交代の例を挙げて」いるわけではありませんよね？  "どういう「基準」なのでしょうか？">> 辞書にも『「交代」は、「世代交代」のように、その役目などが一回限りの場合に、「交替」は、「昼夜交替」「交替での勤務」のように、繰り‌​返される場合に使われることが**多い**。ただし**絶対的なものではなく**、「参勤交代」などは伝統的に「交代」を使う。』とあるのですから、『かくかくしかじかのように区別して使われることが多い、使われる傾向がある。絶対ではないが。新聞用字用語辞典は「交代」に統一しているので、新聞では区別されず全てに「交代」が使われている。』ということを質問者に教えて差し上げればそれでよいではありませんか。

Comment: あ、ちなみにサンキンコウタイについては、徳川の時代から[交代と交替が両方使われており](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%82%E5%8B%A4%E4%BA%A4%E4%BB%A3)、本来どっちでも正解みたいです。明治以降の学校教育でなんとなく「交代」に統一されたため、中学受験レベルなら「交代」の方が無難のようですが。

Comment: ではchocoさんは次世代を次世替とも言いかえると言う訳ですな？その論理によれば同じ係り文字の交で代＝替ならそう言い換えれる筈。そんな日本語有りましたか？　というか結局何を仰りたいので？　上に書いた通りタイムスパンの長さの違いが原因では無いのでしょうか？

Comment: Blavius氏は**mostly interchangeable**と言い切ってしまっている。次世替もOKですね。

Comment: 身代金＝身替金？　代打＝代替？　為替＝為代？　この場合訓読み？で違うなら根源的に何か違う筈。例外有りすぎです。

Comment: "ではchocoさんは次世代を次世替とも言いかえると言う訳ですな？" >> はあ？？ふざけてないでもらえます？「交替」と「交代」の話をしているんですよ。新聞でも「交代」で統一しているのに、『「交代」と「交替」は mostly interchangeable』とBlaviusさんが言ったのがそんなにいけませんか？？ "とい‌​うか結局何を仰りたいので？" >> 先のコメントの通りですが？ なんなんですか、あなた？そもそもBlaviusさんの回答にいちゃもんつけてきたのあなたでしょ。嫌味で返すのなら「コメントウェルカム」なんて書いちゃダメでしょ。  "Blavius氏はmostly interchangeableと言い切ってしまっている。次世替もOKですね。">> ちょっと、やめなさいよ、そういうの。「交替」と「交代」のことを仰ってるんですよ。喧嘩売るんだったらよそのサイトでやってくださいよ。

Comment: まあ別に喧嘩売っていませんがもうええですわ…(m_m).